# Make mailing labels from a list of contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, mailing, address-labels

If I do a search on contacts, the actions menu has an option to generate mailing labels:

[image: Mailing labels action]

However, if I search on recent contributions, the actions does not allow mailing labels (although it does allow generation of **Thank-you Letters for Contributions**):

[image: Contribution actions]

Is there a way to add the **Mailing Labels** action to the contribution actions list?

Comment: Can you get at the same result by doing an advanced search for your contribution criteria and choosing 'display as contacts'? That should allow you to print out mailing labels as an action for the records that your recent contributions are attributed to.

Comment: @EliLisseck, Thanks, I will suggest this. I think it will work but is a few extra steps. If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the same result by doing an advanced search for your contribution criteria and choosing 'display as contacts'? That will allow you to print out mailing labels as an action for the records that your recent contributions are attributed to.

Addition to the comment above:

As @petednz said you can only print mailing labels for contacts, currently. Below is a resource that may help towards developing custom actions if you want to attempt to cut out that extra step, although it may be a bit tricky because I believe most mailing label-type information is stored in the related contact table rather than in the contribution record itself.

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/How+to+Create+Your+Own+Action

Answer (score 2):

Eli is right. Labels can only be generated for Contacts - so your search needs to be based on Contacts and then filter by the relevant Contribution factors that are involved.